# Apache Isis, clone/double form

Tags: forms, isis

I'm working with simple web app.
I have an entity 'Person' that has a reference to another person (its parent).

```
public class Person {
.....
    @javax.jdo.annotations.Column(allowsNull = "true",name = "parentId")
        @Property(editing = Editing.ENABLED)
        private Person parent;
...
```

Apache Isis render the property 'parent' as hyperlink but I have to show it into another tab with all details(the user can't edit parent).
How can I do it?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a read-only view of the *parent's* properties within your *Person* object you might consider 2 options:

1. Add eg. a transient<sup>1</sup> `getParentDetails()` method to your *Person* class, that returns a `Markup` <sup>2</sup> containing pre-formated *Html* to render a summary of the parent's properties that you want to present in this case.
2. For each *parent* property you want to present, add to your *Person* class a transient<sup>1</sup> `getParentFirstName()`, `getParentLastName()`, etc

<sup>1</sup> mark a persistent domain-object's property transient by using the `@javax.jdo.annotations.NotPersistent` annotation
<sup>2</sup> https://isis.apache.org/guides/rgcms/rgcms.html#_rgcms_classes_value-types_Markup